# Nginx. Как открывать файл на сайте, а не скачивать его?

Tags: nginx

У меня есть свой сайт на nginx, и проблема вот в чем. Для примера возьмем файл .py, когда я пытаюсь открыть его в браузере, то этот файл сразу начинает скачиваться, но я хочу чтобы содержимое файла отображалось на сайте, а не скачивался. Как я могу это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вот эти строки нужно добавить в конфиг `nginx`:

```
location ~ \.py$ {
   add_header  Content-Type    text/plain;
}
```

Comment: не помогло. пробовал сначала в главный конфиг nginx.conf, потом в sited-enabled/default, все так же скачивает файл

Comment: @Fl1yd после всех изменений: 1) нужно перегружать nginx `nginx -t && nginx -s reload`. 2) Нужно очищать кэш браузера, в режиме инкогнито или в другом браузере.

Comment: ладно, это сработало. вот теперь следующий вопросик. там каракули, вместо русских букв. это можно исправить?

Comment: @Fl1yd у вас вопросы, которые уже не относятся к текущей теме. [Не ленитесь искать информацию в интернете](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/6293594?hl=ru)

Comment: Галочку напротив ответа поставьте, вместо спасибо

Comment: Может всё таки `text/plain`?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, спасибо. поправил. Вообще без разницы браузеру, вроде как, главное чтобы `text/*` был